Cannot Find Package "fast-glob" While Initializing shadcn with Bunx on Windows 11
I'm trying to set up a Next.js project using Bunx and initialize the shadcn package on Windows 11, but I keep encountering an error related to a missing fast-glob package. I'm running the following commands:

Created a project directory and initialized a Next.js app with:

bunx create-next-app@latest .

Everything worked fine here, and I selected the desired options.

Then I attempted to install and initialize shadcn using the command:

bunx --bun shadcn@latest init

However, I received this error:
error: Cannot find package "fast-glob" from "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\bunx-2275295236-shadcn@latest\node_modules\shadcn\dist\index.js"
I also tried running:
bunx --bun shadcn@latest add

But I encountered the same issue.
I manually installed the fast-glob package, but even after doing that, the same error persists when I attempt to run the above commands again. I’ve tried both the VS Code integrated terminal and the Windows terminal, but neither worked.
Expected Behavior:
I expected the shadcn package to initialize without errors, based on the YouTube tutorial I’m following.
Additional Information:

OS: Windows 11
Bun Version: 1.1.27
Terminals Tried: VS Code Terminal and Windows Terminal

